# Should I return managed object on JPA create/edit

Tags: java, jpa

I've come across a situation where I persist an Entity object in JPA and subsequently have to see if another object `.equals()` it.

However, the test fails because the first object is just a POJO where as the second is its managed equivalent.

Is it good practise to return the newly managed entity object as a result of a JPA create or edit operation?

Regards,
Laurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `hashCode()` and `equals(..)` methods using the fields forming the business key of the object. [See this article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode)

Comment: That article was very helpful.  Unfortunately, I had a problem because I had a tree of self-referencing objects that only had a name field which was not unique. In this situation I had to use the parent objects Id combined with the objects name to uniquely identify.  I couldn't find a better way to do it.

Comment: well, that sounds fair. If an object is uniquely identified by its parent and name - so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two types? A POJO, effectively a DTO and an annotated POJO which is managed? Can you either code an equals method or craft a comparison method that gives unsurprising behaviour?

This gets into all sorts of interesting questions about what "equality" means. My insticnt here is to provide a `hasTheSameValueAs()` method.

To answer your question directly, it does seem very convenient on occasions to do return the managed object.